# Is it possible to add a new numpy column that sums values of existing numpy column in rows meeting condition in another existing column

Tags: python, numpy, sum, conditional-statements, calculated-columns

For each NumPy row n, I would like to add a third column with a value equal to a sum of values in the second column (only for rows at or below row n) where the value of the first column is less than the value in row n +10. The first column has values monotonically increasing.
Example array input:

```
    [[ 1   5] 
     [ 3   5]
     [ 7   5] 
     [11   5] 
     [25   5]]
```

Desired array output:

```
    [[ 1   5  15] 
     [ 3   5  15]
     [ 7   5  10] 
     [11   5   5] 
     [25   5   5]]
```

For the first row, the first column value is 1, so only rows 1,2, and 3 in column 1 have values lower than 1+10. Hence column 2 values (5+5+5) in rows 1,2,3 are summed and placed in the third column of the first row.

For the second row, the first column value is 3, so only rows 2,3, and 4 in column 1 have values lower than 3+10. Hence column 2 values (5+5+5) in rows 2,3 and 4 are summed and placed in the third column of the second row.

For the third row, the first column value is 7, so only rows 3 and 4 in column 1 have values lower than 7+10. Hence column 2 values (5+5) in rows 3 and 4 are summed and placed in the third column of the third row.

The same approach is done for the remaining rows.

Does anyone have the experience to do this in NumPy using a simple and fast computation approach?

Comment: Can you edit the question to clarify whether the array is sorted by the first column so that column is monotonically increasing?  From the examples it looks like for row N you ignore all previous rows and consider only row N and subsequent rows--is that right?  Can you show how you have tried to approach any part of this problem or a simplified version of it?

Comment: To answer your question, the first column is monotonically increasing. I edited my original question with this update. I did not have a solution.

Comment: I've proposed an edit to clarify that the sum ignores preceding rows--I hope that's right?  However, I've downvoted the question for now because so far it doesn't show any research effort.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using two for loops

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1,5],[3,5],[7,5],[11,5],[25,5]])
output_arr=[]
start_index=0 #To loop through from current position to the end 
for item in arr:
    sum=0
    for next_item in (arr[start_index:]): 
        if(item[0]+10 > next_item[0]): #For the required logic
            sum=sum+next_item[1]
    item=np.append(item,sum) #Append the third column to the item array        
    output_arr.append(list(item))
    start_index=start_index+1 #This will move to the next item
print(output_arr)
```

Output

```
[[1, 5, 15], [3, 5, 15], [7, 5, 10], [11, 5, 5], [25, 5, 5]]
```

Comment: Thank you for creating this solution. I tried it on a large array and it worked well. Is there maybe a way to speed it up somehow?